# Check user status, and then, if everything is alright, check if admin; with PHP (mysql database)

Tags: php, mysql, admin

After a successful validation of a user in the database ('email' and 'pass') I need to check for the user 'status' (1=True), and if it's true to check if user is 'admin' (1=True) and to redirect him accordingly. Thank you in advance! P. S. Quoted words are exact table names.

The code is as it follows (everything works, except those two steps):

```
$errors = array(); // Initialize error array.

// Validate the email address:
if (empty($email)) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address.';
} else {
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($email));
}

// Validate the password:
if (empty($pass)) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';
} else {
    $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($pass));
}

if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's OK.

    // Retrieve the user_id and first_name for that email/password combination:
    $q = "SELECT user_id, first_name FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')";      
    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

    // Check the result:
    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {

        // Fetch the record:
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        // Return true and the record:
        return array(true, $row);

    } else { // Not a match!
        $errors[] = 'The email address and password entered do not match those on file.';
    }

} // End of empty($errors) IF.

// Return false and the errors:
return array(false, $errors);
```

} // End of check_login() function.

Comment: Your English is definitely alright. Relax.

Comment: You should probably add "status" and "admin" to your SELECT-Statemant to use it.