# PHP function to check whether a user is admin or not

Tags: php, session, mysqli

i'd need some fancy code to check if a user in the user table has the adm field set to 1 (true).. Tbh i tried reading other posts like this [Check user status, and then, if everything is alright, check if admin; with PHP (mysql database)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054422/check-user-status-and-then-if-everything-is-alright-check-if-admin-with-php) but I haven't been able to understand/adapt to my case..

I have a functions.php in which there are stored some (wow) functions to make login secure (encrypting, anti brute-force, new login, login check) and i tried to make a adm_check function that: reads into $_SESSION to find id and pass, then selects adm fields and returns true if that is equal to 1.. Here's the code

```
function adm_check($mysqli) {

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'])) {

         $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

         $username = $_SESSION['username'];     

         $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 

         if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT adm FROM members WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) { 

                $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id); 

                $stmt->execute(); 

                $stmt->store_result();

            if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

               if($adm==1){
                  return true;
               } 
           } 
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function does only return false, even if the user is correctly set adm into members table.. how should i procede? should i use another method?

Comment: You never set `$adm`. Looks like you just forgot to call `$stmt->bind_result()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting $adm coreectly. You are never assigning it to anything from the query. Here is a solution.

```
    function adm_check($mysqli) {

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

        $username = $_SESSION['username'];     

        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT adm FROM members WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) { 

            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id); 

            $stmt->execute(); 

            $stmt->bind_result($adm);

            $stmt->fetch();

            if( $adm == 1 ) {
                return true;
            }
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I hadn't seen that, thank you for pointing it out. After using your code it still wasn't working, then i realized i forgot to use the session_start() which contained all the infos i needed for the admin check.